# Nonlinear mixed effects model - object not found

Tags: r, lme4

I want to create nonlinear mixed effect model in R using this formula: `h=1.30+(dbh^2/(b0+b1*dbh)^2)`.

in this equation b0 is a random factor and is computed as: `a0+a1*BA+a2*VH+a3*QM+a4*NH` where `a0`, `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `a4` are linear regression coefficients.

I have consulted with different chatbots. They recommend different packages and syntaxes for doing so. None of them run successfully.

Your recommendation appreciated.

look at this code which was created by bing chatbot:

```r
library(lme4)
# Define the nonlinear function
h <- function(dbh, b0, b1) {
  1.30 + (dbh^2 / (b0 + b1 * dbh)^2)
}
# Define the random factor
b0 <- function(a0, a1, BA, a2, VH, a3, QM, a4, NH) {
  a0 + a1 * BA + a2 * VH + a3 * QM + a4 * NH
}
# Define some starting values
start_list <- list(
  # Nonlinear parameters
  nlpars = c(b1 = 0.5),
  # Linear parameters
  theta = c(a0 = 0.1, a1 = 0.2, a2 = 0.3, a3 = 0.4, a4 = 0.5)
)
# Fit the model using nlmer with start argument
model <- nlmer(h(dbh) ~ h(dbh, b0(a0, a1, BA, a2, VH, a3, QM, a4, NH), b1) ~ (a0 | ID), data = your_data, start = start_list)
```

Running this code gave me this error:

> Error in h(dbh) : argument "b0" is missing, with no default

Edit: @GregorThomas
I edited the left hand side of the model formula as: h(dbh, b0, b1). R gave me this error:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'b1' not found.

here is the output of dput command:

```
structure(list(dbh = c(22L, 87L, 110L, 27L, 69L, 34L, 49L, 89L, 
49L, 87L, 46L, 66L, 74L, 48L, 81L, 26L, 89L, 66L, 100L, 50L, 
74L, 29L, 82L, 58L, 75L, 63L, 100L, 54L, 54L, 64L), h = c(11.4, 
32.1, 31.3, 35.3, 40, 23.6, 34, 35, 30, 43, 36, 41.3, 40, 33.3, 
40.6, 21.4, 39.2, 42, 44, 36.5, 39.6, 24, 29, 39.5, 37, 42, 41.3, 
34.5, 37, 40), BA = c(27.71, 27.71, 43.35, 43.35, 26.48, 26.48, 
34.33, 34.33, 35.29, 35.29, 28.61, 28.61, 39.86, 18.1, 18.1, 
29.8, 29.8, 30.2, 30.2, 47.1, 47.1, 30.69, 30.69, 31.78, 31.78, 
45.49, 45.49, 9.34, 9.34, 34.65), VH = c(393.76, 393.76, 672.33, 
672.33, 388.41, 388.41, 526.63, 526.63, 538.45, 538.45, 396.61, 
396.61, 592.49, 249.89, 249.89, 445.99, 445.99, 466.5, 466.5, 
710.59, 710.59, 447, 447, 477.61, 477.61, 726.05, 726.05, 122.4, 
122.4, 553.31), QMD = c(36.8, 36.8, 53.9, 53.9, 43.3, 43.3, 54, 
54, 51.4, 51.4, 36.1, 36.1, 62.5, 27.2, 27.2, 43.5, 43.5, 46.2, 
46.2, 48, 48, 37.3, 37.3, 47.4, 47.4, 60.2, 60.2, 25.7, 25.7, 
60.6), NH = c(260L, 260L, 190L, 190L, 180L, 180L, 150L, 150L, 
170L, 170L, 280L, 280L, 130L, 310L, 310L, 200L, 200L, 180L, 180L, 
260L, 260L, 280L, 280L, 180L, 180L, 160L, 160L, 180L, 180L, 120L
)), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Non-linear mixed-effects models are difficult. This is not something a chatbot (i.e., a language model) can do for you because there won't be sufficient good examples in the training data. The code provided by the chatbot has at least one obvious issue (the LHS of the model formula). Anyway, I strongly recommend using package nlme.

Comment: When you write `h(dbh) ~ ...` you are calling the `h()` function giving it only the input `dbh`, but you have defined `h()` to need 3 inputs: `dbh`, `b0` and `b1`.  The left hand side of your model formula should just be the name of the column in your data that is the response. (You don't show any sample data or describe the structure of your data frame, but we can be more specific with our help if you do that. Better yet, share some data reproducibly with `dput`, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:30, ])` for the first 30 rows.)

Comment: Hi! The problem are the function `h().`. When you create a function, R expects you provide the information of all the parameters that you indicated. Nevertheless, you did not indicate all the parameter in `h(dbh)`.

Comment: @Ben Bolker Thank you very much and sorry for violating SO rules regarding chatbots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here.

This is **not** a "mixed model" by the standard definition; mixed models always involve a *grouping variable*, and allow parameters of the top-level (linear or nonlinear model) to vary across the levels of the grouping variable. What you have is a sort of hierarchical model, but the second-level model (i.e. the model for `b0` as a function of `BA`, `VH`, `QMD`, `NH`) is a linear model, not a sample from a joint distribution.

You can get this done using `gnls` ("generalized nonlinear least squares"), from the `nlme` package:

```r
library(nlme)
gnls(h ~ 1.30 + (dbh^2/(b0 + b1*dbh^2)),
     params = list(b0 ~ BA + VH + QMD + NH, b1 ~ 1),
     data = dd,
     start = list (b0 = rep(1,5), b1 = 1))
```

Plot fitted (predicted) vs observed:

```r
par(las = 1, bty = "l")
plot(predict(m1), dd$h)
abline(a=0, b= 1, col = 2, lwd = 2)
```

[image]

You should also probably be aware that, for better or worse, [chatbot-generated code is highly controversial on Stack Overflow at present](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425293/does-the-chatbot-ban-include-ai-generated-code-in-questions) ...